# useLazyQuery not getting data from the cache when status is rejected from the api

Tags: rtk-query

I am using RTK Query in my React TypeScript project. The issue is that when I manually call the API using useLazyQuery, it only retrieves data from the cache if the status of the data is success. Otherwise, it does not give me data from the cache. For example, if I send an API request to check if an email is present in the database and the API fetches the email from the database, the data will be stored in the cache. After the initial API request, it will retrieve the data from the cache. However, if the email is not present in the database, it will call the API every time.
I am using useLazyQuery like this.
 `const [getCompanyDetail, {isLoading: isSignupLoading}] = useLazyCompanyDetailQuery() const res = await getCompanyDetail(params,true)`

I expect it to get data from the cache even in the rejected case

Comment: what do you mean by "it will call the API every time".
can you provide some more code ?